# ASP.NET CalendarExtender Change culture in an Ajax Panel without refreshing page?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, cultureinfo, calendarextender

I have an ASP.NET page that utilizes an ASP.NET CalenderExtender inside an Ajax UpdatePanel.  A user can choose from several different languages.  I need the Calendar to change with the updated Culture info without the entire page refreshing.

The culture info is being updated for the thread

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(culture)
```

And

```
EnableScriptGlobalization="true"
EnableScriptLocalization="true"
```

What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Vaguely related to what I'm working on now... a couple of suggestions that might help:
- I also do this just after doing "Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ..."

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

I personnally build my CalendarExtender dynamically, but the important line is the Format:

```
ce = new CalendarExtender();
ce.ID = "CalExtender";
ce.Format = ShortDatePatternDoubleDigit;
```

and elsewhere I've got this static method:

```
public static string ShortDatePatternDoubleDigit
    {
        get
        {
            string shortDatePattern = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
            if (!shortDatePattern.Contains("MM"))
                shortDatePattern = shortDatePattern.Replace("M", "MM");
            if (!shortDatePattern.Contains("dd"))
                shortDatePattern = shortDatePattern.Replace("d", "dd");
            if (!shortDatePattern.Contains("yyyy"))
                shortDatePattern = shortDatePattern.Replace("yy", "yyyy");
            return shortDatePattern;
        }
    }
```

as we have clients in the US and in the UK, the date must work in either mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy (and we use the masked edit extender hence the use of two digits for days and months).

On the client side of things, in javascript I can access the format string like this (getter), but I don't know if it can be set, I've not tried. It might help you in your "no postback" scenario:

```
var dateBox = $get('xxxx_DatePicker_TextBox');
var dateFormat = dateBox.CalendarBehavior._format; //this contains dd/MM/yyyy for example
```

Note that you might have to change this format again, for example, I'm using the jQuery UI datepicker, and MM is interpreted as Month Full Name, whereas in C# MM is a two-digit month. Worse, yyyy in C# is four-digit year, but for jQuery datepicker, yy is the four-digit year, so yyyy would end up with 20152015. You could do a dirty:

```
_format.replace(/M/g, "m").replace(/yy/g, "y")
```